# Using UNNEST with jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, jooq, postgresql-9.4

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4, Spring Boot 1.3.2 and jOOQ 3.7. I'd like to "jOOQify" the following query

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE username IN (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(?))
```

so that I can run it with Spring's `JdbcTemplate` by passing a list or array (in this particular case, an `List<String>`). I've tried

```
DSLContext.select(
    USERS.ID
)
.from(
    USERS
)
.where(
    USERS.USERNAME.in(...)
)
```

but I can't figure out what to place in `...`. I tried something like

```
DSLContext.select(field("*")).from(unnest(myList))
```

but unfortunately the compiler doesn't like that. Is there any simple way I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you pass an array? `where username = ANY ( array )` would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't like your attempt, because `USERS.USERNAME` is a `Field<String>`, and thus the `in()` method expects a `Select<? extends Record1<String>>`.

You can fix it as such:

```
select(field("*", String.class)).from(unnest(myList))
```

Or, perhaps a bit better:

```
select(field(name("v"), String.class)).from(unnest(myList).as("t", "v"))
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thanks for the great framework. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries 
how could I build unnest expression for an array and put named parameter in it? I'm a bit lost in types

Comment: @Capacytron: Can you ask a new question with more details please? This one here is about PostgreSQL (with jOOQ), not BigQuery, and without named parameters. Is yours still about BigQuery and jOOQ? Anyway, best ask a new question.