# Convert SQL into JOOQ query

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

What is the JOOQ equivelent of the below query?

```
SELECT e."e_request_id", e."e_participant_id"
FROM "e_request_participation" e
         JOIN (SELECT unnest(array ['clh9omw2o00000134toygpm7o', 'clh5gs4rb0000wy34v69u2usm']) as request_id) r ON e."e_request_id" = r.request_id
         JOIN (SELECT unnest(array ['cldzqdwou0000pu3604veic10', 'cl98n9e7100003x36zaeh7hma']) as participant_id) p
              ON e."e_participant_id" = p.participant_id;
```

Comment: Have you tried [jOOQ's `unnest()` support]https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/array-and-cursor-unnesting/), see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/35555119/521799, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36572388/521799 and many others. What didn't work? What are you struggling with, specifically?

Comment: Note that you don't really need `unnest()` in your case. You can just use an ordinary `IN` predicate.